# How to prevent svg img from being affected by button parent transform property on any pseudo class?

Tags: html, svg, sass, css-selectors, transform

In other words, preventing children from being affected by parent property

so i tried to rotate these `button`s on hover first then other things, but let's focus on hover for now, but the problem is that it rotates the nested `img` too..

i tried many things to prevent it, but the `img` kept rotating
best solution so far is rotate it oppositely, I'm not satisfied at all with this solution cause it rotates again on mouse leave

here's some code been using

```
<div class="h2_2006">
      <button class="h2_2601">
        <img class="h2_2611" title="Add To Cart" src="https://s.svgbox.net/materialui.svg?ic=add_photo_alternate" alt="Add To Cart"> 
      </button>

      <button class="h2_2602">
        <img class="h2_2621" title="Watch" src="https://s.svgbox.net/materialui.svg?ic=alarm_add" alt="Watch">
      </button>

      <button class="h2_2603">
        <img class="h2_2631" title="Fav" src="https://s.svgbox.net/materialui.svg?ic=auto_awesome" alt="Add To Favorite">
      </button>
    </div>
```

and some scss with failed `:after` pseudo examples

```
//scss
.h2_2006 {
        @include grid(1fr 1fr 1fr, 1fr);
        align-items: center;
        grid-gap: 3.3vw;

        >button {
            justify-content: center;
            display: flex;
            align-content: center;
            max-height: 5.2em;
            max-width: 5.2em;
            border-radius: 50%;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            transition: all 1s;
            position: relative;

            &:after {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
                transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
            }

            &:hover:after {
                transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
                transition: all 1s;
            }

            >:not(img) {
                pointer-events: auto;
            }
        }

        .h2_2601 {
            @include pos(auto, 1, 2, center, center);
            background: linear-gradient(134deg, rgb(10, 32, 58) 50%, rgb(15, 48, 87) 50%);


            .h2_2611 {
                z-index: 1;
                outline: none;
                transform-origin: 0 0 0;

            }

        }

        .h2_2602 {
            @include pos(auto, 1, 3, center, center);
            background: linear-gradient(134deg, rgb(15, 48, 87) 50%, rgb(10, 32, 58) 50%);
            content: "";

            &:hover,
            &:focus {
                outline: none;
                transform: rotate(0.5turn);
                transition: transform 1s;
            }

            .h2_2621:hover {
                outline: none;
                transform: rotate(-180deg);
                transition: transform 1s;


            }


        }


    }
```

now, idk what have i missed out here cause i'm turnin off already

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a css class affects everything within it. So, if you do not want your svgs to be rotated, you can place the rotating class on something more specific (like adding another div for only those items that need to be rotated, so long as they are just siblings).

If you need a parent in the hierarchy to be rotated, but not the child, then you can specify the counter-style on the child (which you mentioned as a method you would not like to use)

The important thing to understand here is that your svg within the button is like putting a picture on a disc - if you rotate the disc, the picture will appear to rotate too, unless you rotate it in the opposite direction.

Here is an [interesting article](https://css-tricks.com/a-specificity-battle/) about different layers of specifying css. Perhaps this can help you find a solution

Comment: uff! thanx, now i get it! just wanna note out, this counter styling i didn't mean it's not preferable. i wasn't much explicit, it's just when mouse leaves the svg, it rotates in the counter rotation, which is not preferable

Comment: I'm glad you understand now :-)
If my answer was helpful, please don't forget to upvote it!

Comment: sorry but i can't yet, still new and  need more reputation to upvote.
but surely this will be the first thing to upvote! ;D
just tbh your answer was helpful but not resolving, now i have got rid of the idea and looking for another idea, as the previous one seemed unrealistic to me.
but hey thanx anyway